# .NET: Strange behaviour of double.Equals() when boxing

Tags: .net, comparison, boxing

What's going on here?

```
int zero = 0;
double x = 0;
object y = x;

Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(zero)); // True
Console.WriteLine(y.Equals(zero)); // False
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here, you're calling two different methods - `Double.Equals(double)` and `Object.Equals(object)`. For the first call, `int` is implicitly convertable to `double`, so the input to the method is a `double` and it does an equality check between the two `double`s. However, for the second call, the `int` is *not* being cast to a `double`, it's only being boxed. If you have a look at the `Double.Equals(object)` method in reflector, the first line is:

```
if (!(obj is double))
{
    return false;
}
```

so it's returning false, as the input is a boxed `int`, not a boxed `double`.

Good catch!