# Weird Int64.Equals behaviour

Tags: c#, types

Why this test is failing?

```
    [Test]
    public void Int64Test()
    {

        Int64Keys ObjBigInt = new Int64Keys();
        ObjBigInt.Id = 0;
        PropertyInfo p = ObjBigInt.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
        var IDValue = p.GetValue(ObjBigInt, null);
       //var IDType = IDValue.GetType(); //returns {System.Int64}
        Assert.IsTrue(IDValue.Equals(0)); //is returning  false and the type if IDValue is Int64()


    }

   public class Int64Keys
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    }
   public class Int32Keys
    {
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class DoubleKeys
    {
        public double Id { get; set; }
    }
```

I  [referred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780022/net-strange-behaviour-of-double-equals-when-boxing)  this question but not getting enough idea to fix this.

Edit:
I am using Repository pattern so my instance could be any type(Int32,Int64, double).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `IDValue` will be `object` - because `PropertyInfo` doesn't know any better. You're therefore calling `object.Equals(object)` for `IDValue.Equals(0)`. That's boxing the *Int32* value 0... and the override of `Equals(object)` in `Int64` checks that it really is an `Int64` you're comparing it with. In this case it's not, so it's returning false.

As other answers have said, use `Equals(0L)` to make it return true.

Note that if `IDValue` were strongly typed as `Int64`, it would already be returning true - because then the compiler would prefer the call to `Int64.Equals(Int64)`, promoting the `Int32` to an `Int64`:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Int64 i64 = 0L;
        Console.WriteLine(i64.Equals(0)); // True

        object boxed = i64;
        Console.WriteLine(boxed.Equals(0)); // False
        Console.WriteLine(boxed.Equals(0L)); // True        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a boxed `long` to an `int`.  Boxed primitives will compare not-equal to any object that is not exactly of its own type.  Change this line:

```
Assert.IsTrue(IDValue.Equals(0));
```

To this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(IDValue.Equals(0L));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Assert.IsTrue(IDValue.Equals(0L));